# JavaScript moving an object from starting location to ending location

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm currently taking a course on intro to computer programming.  It's an online course and doesn't have much help when you're stuck.

I'm using Brackets and p5.js and I'm given a template to start off with.  I seem to have done everything needed so far, but I'm not able to animate the spotlight to move.

I believe I haven't initialized the spotlight properly but I've tried multiple different ways.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.  Code below.

- Edit the spotlight object by creating x and y properties initialised to your location. Also endX and endY properties initialised to Marvin's location
- Make the spotlight move perfectly from you towards Marvin by adjusting the increments of the x and y properties.
  If you get everything correct then it will stop over the target.

  - Adjust x and y properties using
  - "+=" or "+"
  - "-=" or "-"

*/

```
var x;
var y;

var startX = 360;
var endX = 575;

var startY = 760;
var endY = 570;


// other variables, you don't need to change these
var img, spotlight_image;

var spotlight;


function preload()
{
    img = loadImage('scene.png');


    spotlight_image = loadImage('spotlight.png')

}

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(img.width, img.height);

    //Initialise the spotlight object
  //with properties x, y, endX and endY
    x = 360;
    y = 760;
    endX =575;
    endY = 570;



  spotlight = {
            image: spotlight_image

        }

}

function draw()
{
    image(img, 0, 0);

    // alter the object properties x and y below to animate the spotlight

    x += 1;
    y +=1;


    ////////// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW /////////////

    //stop the spotlight if it goes off of the screen
    spotlight.x = min(spotlight.x, 960);
    spotlight.y = min(spotlight.y, 945);
    spotlight.x = max(spotlight.x, 0);
    spotlight.y = max(spotlight.y, 0);

    if (abs(spotlight.endX - spotlight.x) < 50
        && abs(spotlight.endY - spotlight.y) < 50)
    {
        spotlight.x = spotlight.endX;
        spotlight.y = spotlight.endY;
    }

    var spotlightSize = 180;

    blendMode(BLEND);
    background(10);
    image(spotlight.image, spotlight.x-spotlightSize/2,
            spotlight.y-spotlightSize/2, spotlightSize, spotlightSize);
    blendMode(DARKEST);
    image(img, 0, 0);

    ////////// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE /////////////
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x`, `y`, `endX`, `endY` have to be properties of `spotlight`:

```js
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(1000, 1000);

    spotlight = {
            image: spotlight_image,
            x: 360,
            y: 760,
            endX: 575,
            endY: 570,
        }
}
```

Increment `spotlight.x` and `spotlight.y`, rather than `x` and `y`:

```js
function draw()
{
    image(img, 0, 0);

    // alter the object properties x and y below to animate the spotlight

    spotlight.x += 1; // <-----
    spotlight.y += 1; // <-----

    ////////// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW /////////////

    //stop the spotlight if it goes off of the screen
    spotlight.x = min(spotlight.x, 960);
    spotlight.y = min(spotlight.y, 945);
    spotlight.x = max(spotlight.x, 0);
    spotlight.y = max(spotlight.y, 0);

    if (abs(spotlight.endX - spotlight.x) < 50
        && abs(spotlight.endY - spotlight.y) < 50)
    {
        spotlight.x = spotlight.endX;
        spotlight.y = spotlight.endY;
    }

    var spotlightSize = 180;

    blendMode(BLEND);
    background(10);
    image(spotlight.image, spotlight.x-spotlightSize/2,
            spotlight.y-spotlightSize/2, spotlightSize, spotlightSize);
    blendMode(DARKEST);
    image(img, 0, 0);

    ////////// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE /////////////
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, when I place the variables under spotlight, I receive an error (unexpected identifier.)

I'm new to this forum, and have a screenshot showing the error and that I've updated the code as you suggested but cannot upload it.

under spotlight, x is showing as Unexpected identifier in the console.

Comment: @Renzo Then you made a mistake. All you've to do is to replace the function `setup` and `draw`, with that one, which I've  provided in the answer. Note, there are changes in `setup`, too.

Comment: I understand, setup is where the error is appearing. 

function setup()
{
 createCanvas(img.width, img.height);

 //Initialise the spotlight object
  //with properties x, y, endX and endY
    


  spotlight = {
   image: spotlight_image,
    x = 360,
    y = 760,
    endX =575,
    endY = 570,
      
  }
   
}

Comment: @Renzo `:` rather than `=`

Comment: You are beautiful and I don't deserve you.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for a better first experience on this forum.  Thank you again.